# Auto-fill the date in a cell, when the user enters information in an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, date, auto-populate

I have a spread sheet, where people can enter project updates and then the date of the update. What is happening is that people are forgetting to date their notes. Is there a way to have the date cell autopoplute the current/date of entry?

I am assuming an if function would do it?

Comment: It would. But how it would depends on the existing design of your worksheet.

Answer (score 5):

This *event macro* will place the date in column **B** if a value is entered in column **A.**  The macro should be installed in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Change the code to use different columns.

**EDIT#1:**

This version will not overwrite material already present in column **B**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
               r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: can the code be modified to only fill in the date IF there isn't already a date (or any value) filled in in column B? I tried adding an IF and using offset, but I couldn't get it to work.. can you help me with this? - [From another answer by sofie](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33937777/4099593)

Comment: @BhargavRao  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: That's nice. +1 from me :) ... Hope "sofie" sees it.

Comment: It looks as though B As Range is unused?

Comment: @BrettDrake **B** is used, but we refer to it by using an `Offset` from the **A** cell.

Answer (score 2):

ZAT's answer worked for me... AFTER I changed the ";"s to ","s.

```
=IF(AND(D52<>"",D52<>0),NOW(),"")
```

I used "NOW" instead of "TODAY" to give me the time of day.

Comment: Whether you should use colon or semicolon depends on your language settings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula in the desired cell (e.g C13) to fill the current date when corresponding input cell (e.g D13) is not empty and not filled with 0 :

```
=IF(AND(D13<>"";D13<>0);TODAY();"")
```

And then you can copy this formula to the subsequent cells to fill in the formulas for that column (e.g col C)

Comment: This is a better solution, however if I make edit anywhere like D13,D14,D15 it changes the date/time in all cells where the formula runs. What I want is..When the D13 is edited it should show the time of edit n E13. When the D14 is edited, it should show the time of edit of D14 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

**Enter Date & Time in column A & B with the data entry in column D**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
Set A = Range("D:D")
Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each r In Inte
        If r.Value > 0 Then
           r.Offset(0, -3).Value = Date
           r.Offset(0, -3).NumberFormat = "dd-mm-yyyy"
           r.Offset(0, -2).Value = Time
           r.Offset(0, -2).NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss AM/PM"
        Else
           r.Offset(0, -3).Value = ""
           r.Offset(0, -2).Value = ""
        End If
    Next r
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```