# Auto-fill date based on value

Tags: vba, excel

What the code does:

Enter a name in column C, date populates in column K.

Other:

1. Drop down in column J can be "registered" or "locked"
2. When data is entered in column C it auto populates "registered" in column J

Here is the code:

```html
'Adds date when borrower name is entered
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("C:C")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            If r.Offset(0, 8).Value = "" Then
               r.Offset(0, 8).Value = Date
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I got this code from: [Auto-fill the date in a cell, when the user enters information in an adjacent cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411407/auto-fill-the-date-in-a-cell-when-the-user-enters-information-in-an-adjacent-ce)

What I would like the code to do:

If column J is "registered" add date to column K (Which is currently does)

If column J is changed to "locked", add date to column L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resize the destination to two columns wide and add 'Registered" along with the date.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Columns(3), Target) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_SafeExit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim C As Range
        For Each C In Intersect(Columns(3), Target, Target.Parent.UsedRange)
            If IsEmpty(C.Offset(0, 8)) Then
               C.Offset(0, 7).Resize(1, 2) = Array("registered", Date)
            End If
        Next C
    End If
bm_SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I've found that if you are going to process multiple Target cells (e.g. from a paste operation) then the loop through the [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa195772(v=office.11).aspx) of Target and your predetermined column should also be pared down to the extents of the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx). Without it, a large number of blank cells would be looped through on a full column paste operation.